# Custom module to validate fields

Tags: 7, forms

I am trying to create a custom module using webforms drupal 7 to carry out some form of validation. All i want the module to do to check if a value of one field (A) is entered then the other field (B) should be zero and if the value of field (B) is entered then the value of field (A) is zero. Anybody able to help? I am a newbee to drupal.

Answer (score 1):

[Webform Validation](http://drupal.org/project/webform_validation) to the rescue!

> This module adds an extra tab to each webform node, allowing you to
>   specify validation rules for your webform components. You can create
>   one or more of the predefined validation rules, and select which
>   webform component(s) should be validated against those.

Comment: OK so how do i get to create my own custom validation rules using webform validation? Does it have that provision besides the predefined conditions?

Comment: The [documentation](http://drupal.org/node/908596) is linked to from the project page.

Comment: Guys i need some help with the code and how to implement it. I want to add an extra validation rule to the webform validation module.